# Как настроить sitemap в битрикс 1с, чтобы в нем были url страниц

Tags: битрикс, sitemap

с толкнулся с такой проблемой, что не получается сделать sitemap, чтобы в нем были url страниц. Я использую генерацию в битрикс, но получаю следующий вид. Может у кого нибудь есть информация сделать sitmap со страницами сайта.

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-files.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-5.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T17:26:39+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-6.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-7.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-8.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-9.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-11.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://aaa-sitrak.ru/sitemap-iblock-12.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-06-23T13:37:52+03:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Comment: Так страницы у вас есть в этих файлах (откройте любой из них). Я в настройках и документации не нашел, как все сделать одним файлом. Если вам нужно, чтобы был один файл, а в нем все ссылки -- можно просто пройтись парсером (например Лягушкой) и выгрузить карту сайта в том виде, в котором вы хотите. Но есть нюанс: это все делать придется ручками